# is there a way to display actionsheet on click of annotation (mapkit ios)

Tags: iphone, mapkit, uiactionsheet

can we display a **UIActionSheet** on click of annotation in the **MapKit**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am doing this and showing popOver on click on annotation so in that case you can create a view and then inside the view do what ever you want.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
{
if([view conformsToProtocol:@protocol(CustomAnnotationViewProtocol)]) 
{
    [((NSObject<CustomAnnotationViewProtocol>*)view)      didSelectAnnotationViewInMap:mapView];
}
}
```

Comment: so are you saying i should initialize UIActionSheet inside the method you provided above?

Comment: yes this is delegate when you touch annotation this method will be called then in this delegate do what ever you want.

Comment: well am i supposed to include any specific protocol in my header file, coz i am getting an error                                            cannot find protocol declaration for 'CustomAnnotationViewProtocol'

Comment: @vin this is my class dude you have to create your own.use only delegate method and show popover and then inside the popover you can set your UIActionSheet.

Comment: i am sorry i am newbie,thanks i will try it out..any idea if i can find some more documentation regarding this?